# A means to access my db in python - what is my problem afterall?

Tags: python, django, web-services, pylons

I have a remote database (at the moment sqlite, but eventually mysql) that I want to be able to call from a webpage dynamically. Basically to query for data that will populate goog viz charts etc on the page (and possibly images).

I have a small, slow server that i can basically run anything on. I've also located the python lib that lets me painlessly generate the data in a format that is friendly for goog viz (http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/gviz_api_lib.html)

but, what i cant understand is how do i go from there to the point where i have a url, to which i can pass arguments and get the data back? googling suggests django (or pylons), but isnt that a bit OTT (i dont have experiance with either). I'm opening to learning how to use them, but atm im very confused as to what exactly i need to be able to run this webservice.

help greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you'll need to do is deploy a web server (**apache** is a common choice).
Once your server is running, you can test it by pushing simple HTML files to it and make sure they are accessible to you from a browser.

Once your server is properly configured, you have a number of options available for interfacing your web-server with Python:

- The easiest is probably to follow the deployment guide of a popular web framework, as you mentioned.

  - [Pylons Deployment Guide](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/0.9.7/gettingstarted/)
  - [Django Installation Guide](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/install/#intro-install)
- You can use mod_python directly, which requires adding boilerplate code around your code to work inside a mod_python instance.

  - [mod_python documentation](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/)
- You can use CGI, which does not scale very well but makes it fairly easy to interact with the web-server:

  - [Python's built-in CGI module](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html)

Comment: Thanks loginx - and in general, for something as basic as this - it still makes sense to go the whole hog and run pylons / django instead of a lighter solution ? ive just come across cherrypy?

Comment: You're right in that a full-fledged web-framework might be overkill. Have a look at [Web.py](http://webpy.org/), it's a tiny little web-framework that has a pretty good reputation, but i haven't used it myself. It seems to be very simple to use.

Comment: Thanks - brilliant. I really appreciate your (very detailed) help :)